# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, ssl

i get a "Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure" for the code below. Does anybody know how to fix it?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;

public class Test {
static {
    System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,SSLv3,SSLv2Hello");
    HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String urlHostName, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL("https://www.sureworks.de").openConnection();
    con.connect();
}
}
```

Comment: What's the output if you run the JVM with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl`?

Comment: What version of Java are you running your test with?  Testing the site using SSLLabs indicates that SNI support is needed to connect to the site.  That would require Java 1.7 or later.

Answer (score 0):

There are some crypto related stuff that isn't enabled by default. You need to install JCE:

- [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 8 Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html)
- [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 7 Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html)

PS: SSL Labs gives you some idea about the server you are trying to access https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?viaform=on&d=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sureworks.de%2F